# Runtime Error 91 - when testing code in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, variables, userform

Office 360, 64 bit, Excel. 
The subroutine, `Private Sub Card_FindCardNumber_AfterUpdate()` is a `textbox (Card_FindCardNumber)` that after I have entered in the number I am querying, the code should be looking to see if it exists.

Whilst testing the code, it doesn't matter whether it is a number that exists or doesn't exist, I get the same error message `"Runtime Error 91", Object Variable or With Block variable not set`.

I'm a amateur with VBA and can't work out why there is a problem with the particular line of code.

I have adapted the code from Trevor Easton,(Online PC Learning) "[Excel VBA with Userform Vlookup](https://www.onlinepclearning.com/excel-vba-userform-vlookup/%20under%20the%20code%20%22Private%20Sub%20Reg1_AfterUpdate().)" from YouTube and his website:

The `Ws01` is actually the Code name of the spreadsheet representing cnVisitorCard_Database worksheet.

The Vlookup is referring to the named range: "LookupCardNo" which has an offset function covering data of 9 columns (from column AC (Card #) to the last column of the name range AK)

```
    Private Sub Card_FindCardNumber_AfterUpdate()
              'Define the Variables
              Dim ws01 As Worksheet
              Dim cnVisitorCard_Database As Worksheet
              Set ws01 = cnVisitorCard_Database

             'Check to see if value exists
             If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws01.Range("AC:AC"), Me.Card_FindCardNumber.Value) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "This is an incorrect ID"
                Me.Card_FindCardNumber.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
             End If

            'Lookup values based on first control
               With Me
                .Card_ExpiryDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 2, 0)
                .Card_Status = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 3, 0)
                .Card_ReturnDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 4, 0)
                .Card_Description = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 5, 0)
                .Card_TypeCode_Hidden = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 6, 0)
                .Card_ValidNo_ofDays_Hidden = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 7, 0)
                .Card_UpdatedInHW = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 8, 0)
                .Card_UpdatedInFF = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), ws01.Range("LookupCardNo"), 9, 0)

                End With

     End Sub
```

I get the error 91 at the line:

```
 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws01.Range("AC:AC"), 
Me.Card_FindCardNumber.Value) = 0 Then
```

I am of course either expecting it to return the values into the textboxes on the Userform if the number exists, but if it doesn't exist, then I'd expect it to slam me with an pop-up message telling me the number doesn't exist.

I'd be most grateful for any assistance :) of course I'd don't know if there will be other errors once this is cleared up.

Comment: Can you omit the line `Set ws01 = cnVisitorCard_Database`  and check if it's running. Also drop the `Dim ws01 as Worksheet`.

Comment: As `ws01` is the code name of the spreadsheet, you don't need to set it.

Comment: I commented out the "Set ws01 = cnVisitorCard_Database " and got the same error (01).

Comment: I commented out the "Dim ws01 as Worksheet", and of course I got the error that states that the variable ws01 has not been defined.

Comment: I have the Option Explicit at the top of the code window, so the worksheet/s would have to be defined … I haven't had a problem with the that part of the code in other projects that I have made

Comment: I tried replacing the ws01 with the codename of the sheet, and it returns the error 91 at the same place as my original submission.

Comment: Then Try replacing `Set ws01 = cnVisitorCard_Database` this with `Set ws01 = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("cnVisitorCard_Database")` ... I am assuming cnVisitorCard_Database is the Name of the sheet. Not CodeName.

Comment: Are you sure you have a control named `Card_FindCardNumber` ?

Comment: @Tim Williams ... Yes, the textbox name is "Card_FindCardNumber" ... and spelling etc is correct as I copy & paste control names directly from the Properties box.  I may have confused all with the Codename of the worksheet in the properties window, the code name for the sheet is "cnVisitorCard_Database " as I always use cn as a prefix for codename

Comment: I have had no problems with defining the worksheet names before (code names), so I'm not sure why it's happening now. But I think after 8+ hours of trying to resolve this ... I'm brain dead/deader!!! so I will have another look tonight when I get home from work .... I'll check if there is any other suggestions, but I'll respond tomorrow :)  THANK YOU ALL VERY MUCH FOR YOUR PATIENCE AND PERSISTENCE ... I really appreciate it ...

Comment: In that case try `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(...)`

Comment: @Tim Williams .. you're faster than a bullet !!! Thank you... I'll check that out and let you know how it goes ... thank you again :)

Comment: What happens if you `Debug.Print Me.Card_FindCardNumber.Value`  ?

Comment: Gah I totally missed that line `Dim cnVisitorCard_Database As Worksheet` , so this line `Set ws01 = cnVisitorCard_Database` just says `Set ws01 = Nothing`, since your declared `cnVisitorCard_Database` "hides" the sheet with the same codename, so your code can't see it...

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a sheet with codename `cnVisitorCard_Database` then this variable declaration will "hide" that sheet:

```
Dim cnVisitorCard_Database As Worksheet
```

so your local variable has a value of `Nothing`.  So when you do this:

```
Set ws01 = cnVisitorCard_Database
```

you are really writing

```
Set ws01 = Nothing
```

This doesn't raise an error, but makes your `Countif` call on the next line fail.

This should work (and the code is a bit simpler/shorter):

```
Private Sub Card_FindCardNumber_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rngSrch As Range, m 'as variant

    Set rngSearch = cnVisitorCard_Database.Range("LookupCardNo")

    m = Application.Match(CLng(Me.Card_FindCardNumber), rngSearch.Columns(1), 0)

    If IsError(m) Then
        'if no match then m is an error value
        MsgBox "This is an incorrect ID"
        Me.Card_FindCardNumber.Value = ""
    Else
        'if found match then m is the matching row number in rngSearch
        With rngSearch.Rows(m)
            Me.Card_ExpiryDate = .Cells(2).Value
            '...etc
            Me.Card_UpdatedInFF = .Cells(9).Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```